# How to decrypt .ts files into separate .ts files with ffmpeg without using a playlist?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, encryption

I have a number of `.ts` files, `.m3u8` playlist and a key to decrypt them. The key is a file, not a hexadecimal string. My goal is to decrypt some of these `.ts` files to analyze them individually. I also obviously don't want to modify the actual video/audio streams in them in any way, just a decryption.

I have no problem decrypting them as an `.m3u8` playlist into one big `.ts` or `.mp4` file with a simple command like `ffmpeg -allowed_extensions ALL -i chunklist.m3u8 -c copy output.ts`, I just use `URI=key` in the playlist and it works. But I need them to be decrypted into separate files, not one.

I could probably just leave only one line in the playlist and decrypt them one by one like this but I want to learn how to do it properly.

I tried opening the key file in a hex editor (which is probably a dumb thing to do) and then using the hex value in a command like `ffmpeg -decryption_key {hex_value} -i part1.ts part1.ts` but it gives me an `Invalid data found when processing input` error...

So how to do this properly? The ffmpeg documentation wasn't helpful...

[Here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/twsn7mdew9aa8lx/test.zip/file) are the files I'm working with in a zip archive. I've included only three of the `.ts` files there, that should be enough for a test.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what I used and it didn't work.

Comment: Specify the input file using the `crypto` protocol – `ffmpeg -key <key> -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -i crypto:part1.ts`

Comment: Or `openssl enc -aes128 -d -K <key> -iv 0 -in part1.ts -out decoded-part1.ts`